# How to get the run time for a PHP script

Tags: php, runtime

So I have been developing a compression engine in PHP (just for started I wanted to use a language I'm familiar with) and wanted to compare times it takes to run scripts.

And by scripts I mean how long it takes to do example:

```
echo "This is some text that I want to know how long it took to display it";
```

I have looked at some Stack questions and all I could find was a `microtime` function which got a number like `6.9141387939453E-6;` - Not sure what that is.

I did manage to get a function to work `getrusage` - But that was on another server that I don't have anymore. I'm running on a Windows version of XAMPP with PHP 5 - So I don't have access to `getrusage`.

So all I want to know is how to get the amount of time (in seconds) it took for the PHP script to run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you'll notice, that goes very fast which makes the result appear to vary a lot from one call to another because it's so small that measuring it induces imprecision.

Here's the code you're looking for:

```
<?php

$start = microtime(true);

echo "This is some text that I want to know how long it took to display it.<br/>";

$duration = microtime(true) - $start;

echo "It took $duration microseconds to run.";
```

Comment: Ah thanks! I was thinking that cause it was a really small float and had the -e that meant it was small, but thanks for confirming :)